# Cannot obtain access token using OAuth2 with Exchange

Tags: azure, exchangewebservices, azure-active-directory

I am attempting to use OAuth2 to access an Exchange mailbox, but I'm having trouble with the OAuth protocol. I'm not using a library, just making direct http calls (using libcurl). I'm using documentation found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code

I have successfully obtained the authorization code, now I'm trying to use that to obtain the access token. The response in the returned json is "invalid grant, Transmission data parser failure: Authorization Code is malformed or invalid.". HTTP error 400. Below is the entire flow that I'm generating:

Obtaining Auth code:

Start IE with this url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=38f1da80-9f80-4ff6-84a8-27c83d7212d3&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fnativeclient&resource=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2F&response_type=code&scope=openid+Mail.ReadWrite
```

At this point, the user is presented with the Microsoft login screen.  He enters his credentials, then is asked to approve access to the requested scopes.  He does so.  Next, at the redirect URL, we receive the data:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient?code=AQABAAIAAAA9kTklhVy7SJTGAzR-p1BcUmXu0izUoOslqxHN85yR0vAVKicFVbtjs3IsKScxeBuTmxBsVy8qT3axn5YaDt_O6M4YVcAk--kpJ-dnNbKtnovjHIxGwtdRawo53UU9u19YP5ST5a8Ekffnxh0Z2gbBM_sKbmbhx2E-y_xs1spgV8gF6im39tLWo
```

Obtaining token:

The application extracts the data after "code=", then posts to this url:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

this data:

```
grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=38f1da80-9f80-4ff6-84a8-27c83d7212d3&code=AQABAAIAAAA9kTklhVy7SJTGAzR-p1BcUmXu0izUoOslqxHN85yR0vAVKicFVbtjs3IsKScxeBuTmxBsVy8qT3axn5YaDt_O6M4YVcAk--kpJ-dnNbKtnovjHIxGwtdRawo53UU9u19YP5ST5a8Ekffnxh0Z2gbBM_sKbmbhx2E-y_xs1spgV8gF6im39tLWo&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fnativeclient&resource=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2F
```

This post results in http error 400, and the returned data is:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS70000: Transmission data parser failure:Authorization Code is malformed or invalid....}
```

Can anybody take a look at what I've done and suggest where I'm going wrong?  As an aside, I have tried running a Powershell script suggested by Shawn - this script uses my existing application ID and obtains an auth code and token using ADAL.  This seemed to work, so I suspect the problem is in my code, not the application configuration in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mixing up the [Azure Active Directory V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview) endpoint with the V1 endpoint.

Specifically, the document you have linked, and say you are following, is meant for the AAD V1 endpoint and uses the following URLS (as documented):

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize`

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token`

> **Note:** There is no `/v2.0/` in the urls.

Another issue I see with your token request is that you are not specifying a `resource`. I believe this is required if you want to acquire an access token to a specific resource. In the case of Exchange Online, you want to specify the resource `https://outlook.office.com/`.

Note that if possible, Office 365 suggests that you use the Microsoft Graph (`https://graph.microsoft.com/`) instead of the Exchange API directly. If you are okay with this, then you should probably also use the AAD V2 endpoint. The equivalent article for the V2 endpoint as the one you listed above is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code).

Let me know if this solves your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I have been trying both endpoints, using registrations that I have done in both the Application Registration Portal and the Azure Management Portal.  In my tests, I did in fact use the non-2.0 endpoint with the application created in the Azure portal.  Still not working.  I did try adding "resource", even though it says optional.  Is this the kind of problem I can get help with if I open a support case with Azure? There are so many moving parts -  I think I need some in-depth consulting, any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jeff, if you have tried different things, you will need to post the specific error messages and results you get at those different steps. It is hard to help debug your situation without those details. If you could update your original message using the **right** endpoint, and the error that results, that would help a lot. Also we should have full working end to end samples on our [GitHub here](https://github.com/azure-samples).

Comment: OK, I've edited the original post to accurately reflect what and where I am posting.